# Coded UI - Filling DataTable from a UI Table (HtmlTable)

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

In Coded UI, I am facing a problem with Filling my Data Table on the top of HTmlTable on the UI.

Actually it is taking a lot of time to fill the datatable when there are 1000 of rows on the UI Table. I am working like this :

```
DataTable TestDataTable = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < Table.RowCount; i++) 
{
   HtmlRow hr = (HtmlRow)Table.Rows[i]; 
   for (int k = 0; k < hr.CellCount; k++) 
   { 
      TestDataTable.Rows[i][k] = hr.Cells[k].FriendlyName; 
   } 
}
```

Its working Fine but as  said it takes a lot of time. So is there any way i could fill the dataTable FASTER ?

Thanks,

Aashish GUpta

Answer (score 0):

Possibly moving `TestDataTable.Rows[i]` out of the inner loop as it may be doing a full table `(i,k)` index evaluation every time.

```
HtmlRow hr = (HtmlRow)Table.Rows[i];
DataRow dest = (DataRow)TestDataTable.Rows[i];
for (int k = 0; k < hr.CellCount; k++) 
{ 
    dest[k] = hr.Cells[k].FriendlyName; 
}
```

Have altered the data type in the code above based on the asker's comment. <strike>As the member types within `DataTable` are not specified I have assumed `HtmlRow` for `dest`.</strike>

Comment: At line HtmlRow dest = (HtmlRow)TestDataTable.Rows[i];
system is giving an exception - Cannot convert type 'System.Data.DataRow' to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.HtmlControls.HtmlRow

Comment: @Aashish The last line of the answer is inviting you to work out the correct type as the type is not stated in the question.

Comment: @Aashish What exactly have you tried and how much investigation have you done? I do not have your code so I cannot try to compile it and give the *exact* solution to your problem. Hence my answers can only be suggestions that you need to experiment with.